# OS X API for integration with text fields

Tags: cocoa, macos

I am developing an application which offers input prediction for users based on a custom dictionary. Is it possible in OS X to gain access to any text field where the user is entering some input, perhaps through some Cocoa API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about the [Accessibility API](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Accessibility/Conceptual/AccessibilityMacOSX/OSXAXIntro/OSXAXintro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001078).